# SSH Error: "Not a RSA1 key file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.", "key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'"

Tags: deployment, heroku, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

```
git push heroku master
```

returns:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer      
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

This is the first time I've tried to push to heroku.

- `heroku login` returns "Authentication successful"
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa was originally created by the heroku command line client - I ran `heroku login` for the first time and it asked if I wanted to generate a key.
- I recreated keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (as specified [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)) and then tried again but in vain.
- Created "authorized_keys" at "~/.ssh" and with my public key in it, no luck.
- Created /etc/hosts.allow with contents "sshd all", still no luck.

Permissions on the keys are : "-rw-------"
Heroku status is O.K.
I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.

```
ssh -vvv myloginname@heroku.com
```

returns:

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011   
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config  
debug1: Applying options for *  
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0   
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.132] port 22.   
debug1: Connection established.   
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.   
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'   
debug3: key_read: missing keytype    
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace   
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace   
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace    
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace   
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace   
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace  
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace   
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace   
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace   
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace     
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace    
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace     
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace     
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace      
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace       
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace       
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace        
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace           
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace            
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace              
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace               
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace               
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace             
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace           
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace             
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'             
debug3: key_read: missing keytype               
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa type 1             
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1            
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa type -1            
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1               
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Did this previously work, and then stop? If you run `$ heroku login` what do you get?

Comment: No,  I'm trying it very first time.                                   And heroku login returns "Authentication successful"

Comment: Smells like a corrupted or invalid private key. How did the file ~/.ssh/id_rsa get created?

Comment: Heroku Command Line Client generated it, running "heroku login" for the first time asked if I wanted to generate one(I didn't have any already). Then to recreate I used "ssh-keygen -t rsa".

Comment: Are you able to go through all these steps? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Answer (score 3):

I had the very same problem (not on heroku) but on my own server.

Try to look in **/var/log/auth.log**
my **~/.ssh/authorized_keys** file was ownd by the wrong user

Answer (score -1):

If I try

> ssh -vvv myloginname@heroku.com

I get this:

```
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
...
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename ~/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename ~/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 2
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 500/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
```

Do you have a known_hosts file in `~/.ssh/`? Mine contains entries for `heroku.com,50.19.85.154 ssh-rsa` and `50.19.85.132 ssh-rsa`. Do you have those?

If you do `which ssh-keygen`, what version of ssh-keygen is being run? Is it the proper copy that should be getting used/that was installed by the Heroku Toolbelt? If not, perhaps the steps from the [Heroku Managing Keys article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) are not creating a valid key?